# How to delete user meta by key

Tags: plugins, user-meta

I'm a beginner with WordPress plugin api, php and ajax.
I'm coding a training plugin for myself to save posts article to read them later, like favourites on web browser, with folders.

I use oop to do so.

I assumed to create a new user meta called 'favoris', wich is an array with the users created folders.

I got something like that for getting favs, creating folders and deleting'em.

```
/**
 * Get favorites
 */
public function fp_ajax_getFav(){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $userid = $current_user->ID;
    $folder = get_user_meta($userid, 'favoris');
    $content =  '';
    $content .= 'Favoris';
    $content .= '';
    $content .= '';
    $content .= '';
    $content .= '';

    if (!empty($folder)) {
        $content .= 'Tout supprimer';
        $content .= 'Aucun favoris.';
    }
    else{
        $content .= 'Tout supprimer';
        $content .= 'Aucun favoris.';
    }

    $content .= '';

    if (!empty($folder)) {
        $msg = '';
        foreach ($folder as $key) {
            foreach ($key as $k => $value) {
                $content .= ' ' . ucwords($value['titre']) . '';
            }
        }
    }
    else{
    }
    $content .= '';
    $content .= '';
    return $content;
}

/**
 * Add folder
 */
public function fp_ajax_addFolder(){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $userid = $current_user->ID;
    $meta = get_user_meta($userid, 'favoris');
    if (empty($meta)) {
        if ($_REQUEST['foldername'] !== '') {
            $folder[0]['titre'] = $_REQUEST['foldername'];
            add_user_meta($userid, 'favoris', $folder);
            var_dump($folder);
            echo ucwords($_REQUEST['foldername']);
            die();
        }
    }
    if (!empty($meta)) {
        $folder = $meta[0];
        if ($_REQUEST['foldername'] != '') {
            foreach ($folder as $key => $value) {
                $i = count($folder);
                if ($value['titre'] != $_REQUEST['foldername']) {
                    $folder[$i]['titre'] = $_REQUEST['foldername'];
                    update_user_meta($userid, 'favoris', $folder);
                    var_dump($folder);
                    echo ucwords($_REQUEST['foldername']);
                    die();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Remove folder
 */
public function fp_ajax_removeFolder(){
    if ( ( !isset($_POST['folderId']) || empty($_POST['folderId']) ) && ( !isset($_POST['folderName']) || empty($_POST['folderName']) ) ) {
        echo 'Pas de dossier spécifié';
        die();
    }
    else{
        $id = $_POST['folderId'];
        $name = $_POST['folderName'];
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $userid = $current_user->ID;
        $folder = get_user_meta($userid, 'favoris');
        $folderToErase = $folder[0][$id];
        try {
            delete_user_meta($userid, 'favoris', $folder[0][$id]);
            echo $folderToErase['titre'];
            //print_r($folder[0][$id]['titre']);
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'not ok';
            var_dump($folder);
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
        die();
    }
}
```

As far as I get or create, everything goes fine. But when I want to remove a folder by key ($id), it doesn't. But when I echo the $folderToErase, the id's right.

Maybe some help ?

Comment: The third parameter for `delete_user_meta()` is a meta _value_ but you refer to it as a "key". Are you sure you are using the function correctly?

Comment: Not sure. I thought it was this way first. But when I use $folder[0][$id]['titre'] as the meta value to delete, it fails as well.

Comment: Exactly what is `var_dump($userid, 'favoris', $folder[0][$id]);`?

Comment: It returns : "string(4) "test"
where test is the folder's name.

Comment: How is `$folder` stored in the database? Is it a serialized array?

Comment: I didn't add custom query. So it's stored as the api's working for.
It looks like that in the database : 
a:3:{i:0;a:1:{s:5:"titre";s:3:"sfg";}i:1;a:1:{s:5:"titre";s:4:"test";}i:2;a:1:{s:5:"titre";s:4:"test";}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're data is stored in a serialized array in the database, per a comment to the question:

```
... it's stored as the api's working for. It looks like that in the database : `a:3:{i:0;a:1:{s:5:"titre";s:3:"sfg";}i:1;a:1:{s:5:"titre";s:4:"test";}i:2;a:1:{s‌​:5:"titre";s:4:"test";}}`
```

You are trying to remove only part of that serialized array by passing the key to `delete_user_meta()`. That is not how [`delete_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_user_meta) works. It is not going to `unserialize()` that value and remove the individual piece of the array. It is going to delete the row in the table where the key and the value match exactly. That is not what you want. With serialized data what you end up with is an array which you need to process yourself.

Something like this should work:

```
//      $id = $_POST['folderId'];
// fake $_POST['folderID']
$id = 'test';
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$userid = $current_user->ID;
//         $folder = get_user_meta($userid, 'favoris');
// fake the get_user_meta call
$folder = unserialize('a:3:{i:0;a:1:{s:5:"titre";s:3:"sfg";}i:1;a:1:{s:5:"titre";s:4:"test";}i:2;a:1:{s:5:"titre";s:4:"test";}}');

try {
  foreach ($folder as $k => $m) {
    if ($m['titre'] === $id) {
      unset($folder[$k]);
    }
  }
  update_user_meta($userid, 'favoris', $folder);
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'not ok';
  return $e->getMessage();
}
```

What you need to do is process the array, removing the parts you don't want, and then re-save it.

Note: As I started writing this code I realized that I was not 100% sure what you were trying to accomplish. The reason behind some of your `$_POST` data isn't completely obvious to me. That should get you on the right track though.

Comment: Weird, when I do a get_user_meta($userid, 'favoris'), I get an array. Tried to unserialize it, of course, doesn't work as it's an array. Waiting for your code. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Neovea : see the edit. I was not completely clear in the original version of the answer, and I added some code.

Comment: I did a bit different finally but I'm going to study your piece of code.

I did an unset on the piece of array I wanted to remove, and then an update_meta_user.

I have now to reorganize the index.

Thanks a lot for helping !

Comment: What you say you did is essentially the same as what I did, even if the details differ.

Comment: Yes was just to say I succeed a bit by myself ;)